# Make my custom view update text fields in editor

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

So im currently working on a custom card view and my goal is pretty easy. I want to update the textfield to the string I set in the custom card view xml.

But somehow I can't get it working after many hours of trying. Sometimes the editor won't load my xml with the custom card view... sometimes it gives me a extremely long error message... and sometimes it just stays black...

Therefore I have the following xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/CallEntry_Holder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:tag="0">

<com.test.larsmatthaus.projectnurser.customs.Custom_CardView

    android:id="@+id/Call_Entry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorCardBackgroundR"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:personName="test"
    app:room="100"
    app:ward="test"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1024dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WardName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Louisa Burgess"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOverlayTC"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_2"
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/icon_1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.85"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/WardName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/teddybear" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_1"
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/WardName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RoomText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="105"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOverlayTC"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/WardName"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seperator_C"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_light"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOverlayTC"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/RoomText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/WardName"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/RoomText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/RoomText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WardText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/anaheim"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ward 2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOverlayTC"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seperator_C"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/WardName"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/seperator_C"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seperator_C" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</com.test.larsmatthaus.projectnurser.customs.Custom_CardView>
```

It contains just one card view entry.

My custom card view class looks like this :

```
public class Custom_CardView{


public Context context;

public Map<Integer, Object> vars = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();


public Custom_CardView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);


    this.context = context;

    setWillNotDraw(false);


    View view = getRootView();


    for(int index = 0; index<((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount(); ++index) {

        View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(index);

        vars.put(nextChild.getId(), nextChild);

    }

    Log.println(Log.DEBUG,"Custom_CardView","<Custom_CardView : Instantiated => ["+vars.size()+"] children>");



    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elements_call_entry, this, true);


    TextView wardText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WardName);
    wardText.setText("TEST");


}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);


}

}
```

I want to update the TextView "wardName" to the attribute value i did set in the xml file...

But somehow the editor view crashes once I load it... Due to the Custom CardView Class... Theres no real error log...

The only one I received was this : **Preview timed out while rendering the layout. This typically happens when there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views**

What did I forgot ? What else could I try to modify the editors textview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was pretty easy... just added a new layout activity which will inflate once the CardView is pressed. I just copy the CardView element and place it inside the inflated view => problem solved :)